# Is it possible to wire an occupancy sensor in this 1950s house with 3-way switches?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I'm looking to replace a pair of 3-way switches with a single Lutron Occupancy sensing switch ([MS-OPS2](https://assets.lutron.com/a/documents/0301654.pdf)). Is it possible to do so and if so, how can I do it? Neutral and ground appear to be present. This is a 1950s house that has undergone renovations at some point. Please see photo for current setup. Thank you!

[image: Photo of current configuration]

Answer (score 4):

### You'll need to return the MS-OPS2 and get the correct switch for your application

Lutron makes Maestro sensors that work in three-way apps, but the MS-OPS2 isn't one of them.  You'll need to return it and get a MS-OPS5M instead.

Comment: But the OP says they want to replace both existing switches with a single sensor.  So I don't see why it can't work.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, provided that you want to put the occupancy sensor where the neutral is.

At the second switch, you need to remove the switch and link one of the travelers to what's currently the output of that switch.  The other traveler isn't needed any more and should be left safely insulated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the correct solution was to cap off 1, 2, 3 in box A, then connect 4 and 7 (black only) to the Lutron sensor. Cap off 5, 6, 7.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts though!